# How to get python to generate random size?

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

I need to make my python code draw my stars in different sizes at random. I've tried every method I know but unable to figure it out...still trying to completely understand loops.

```
import turtle
import random

for n in range(60):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(random.randint(-400, 400), random.randint(-400, 400))
    turtle.pendown()

    red_amount   = random.randint( 0,  100) / 100.0
    blue_amount  = random.randint(0 , 100) / 100.0
    green_amount = random.randint( 0,  100) / 100.0
    turtle.pencolor((red_amount, green_amount, blue_amount))

    turtle.pensize(random.randint(1, 10))

    for i in range(6):
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(144)
        turtle.end_fill()
```

All it does currently is draw stars at the same size.

Comment: You need to correct indentation in your code. Right now it doesn't work.

Comment: `turtle.forward(50)` # not random..

Answer (score 3):

You've added code to randomize the color, starting position and pen width but there's none to change the size of the stars.  The size is controlled by this statement:

```
turtle.forward(50)
```

but you don't want to simply replace the 50 with another call to the random module as your stars will come out irregular.  You need to compute a random size before the loop and then use that size in the `forward()` call in the loop:

```
import turtle
import random

for n in range(60):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(random.randint(-400, 400), random.randint(-400, 400))
    turtle.pendown()

    red_amount = random.random()
    blue_amount = random.random()
    green_amount = random.random()
    turtle.color(red_amount, green_amount, blue_amount)

    turtle.pensize(random.randint(1, 10))

    size = random.randint(25, 100)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(144)

    turtle.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

I've also made a few style changes to your code while I was at it.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes sense!

Comment: Is it possible to know why the fill color isn't working?

Comment: Add `screen.colormode(1)` to the beginning somewhere.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, the `colormode()` is already correct as 1.0 is the default and both Ayla's and my code rely on that.  The *fill color* issue is *fill* which was broken, not *color*.

Comment: @AylaBrooks, I've fixed the code to make *fill* work as well.  However, depending on what type of system you have, you might see something different.  Windows systems will likely see completely filled stars.  Unix systems will likely see stars with just the arms filled but not the center.  If this is an issue, I can provide links to explanations and work arounds.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I also figured out my fill was inside the loop when it needed to be outside of the loop!